# HASHBYTES 'SHA1' return value that differ to standard SHA1 implementation

Tags: sql-server, hash, sha1

I am computing HASH value of each row in a table (for diffing purpose), after implementing the algorithm I am testing the results.
Results are consistent and algorithm somewhat seems to work, but testing it step by step I found a strange result.

The script:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', (SELECT INNERTBL.VALUT FOR XML RAW)) as KHASH
FROM ACLING AS INNERTBL
```

Should perform the SHA1 calculation on the table key, but when I perform the same calculation with external tool I get different results:

[image]

In fact when I perform `SHA1('<row VALUT="A"/>')` with external tool (tool here: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha1.html) I get a different result:

[image]

So my question is, there is something wrong with my logic or simply SQL Server use some non standard SHA1 "parametrization"? (I have suspect about the use of a, may be standard but particular, padding scheme)

Example in fiddler: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efa4e0ba11c112f54e36afb5d54d2cce

Comment: FYI, you should really be using SHA2 now, as per the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) section of the documentation.

Comment: As for your question, we can't access your data, and transcribing it could easily introduce errors. Provide a full [mre] with DDL and DML statements.

Comment: I get the expected value when I transcribe your value as well, so we definitely need that [mre]. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04feb85ecc67857d56d3556d6fde5404)

Comment: @Larnu: you are right, i integrate the question ASAP.
For the SHA256 part, SHA1 is deprecated because is not safe or because Microsoft is planning to remove it? I need a really safe checksum (and SHA1 is by far better than CRC and faster than SHA256) no security is needed

Comment: A quick Google with give a wealth of answers as to why it's deprecated, for example: [SHA-1 collision attacks are now actually practical and a looming danger](https://www.zdnet.com/article/sha-1-collision-attacks-are-now-actually-practical-and-a-looming-danger/)

Comment: @Larnu: thanks again for clarification about the deprecated issue.
For the testability issue, i have integrated the data provided with a fiddler example that reproduce my issue

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK my apologies, i'll keep in mind for future questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1','<row VALUT="A"/>'), --- you are testing this
HASHBYTES('SHA1',N'<row VALUT="A"/>') -- ..but for xml returns Nvarchar
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that you get the same result only if the string are binary the same. For example if the two strings uses different characterset they will have different HASH value. For more details please check thsi out https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18290/is-sha-1-hash-always-the-same